# Open a shared folder on a domain from a web page

Tags: html

Thanks for you help in advance,

I am building a very simple web page , (a single page) with links to e.g bbc.com, cnn.com etc, (this works fine)

now i need to create diff links on that page to various location on our internal shared drive, which is already map to user pc from the server (running win server 2008).

wen users who's systems are not connected to our domain try to access the shared drive (after a shut down) they are always prompted for username and password which then give them access to the drive.

my ques now is how do i create this link on my html page so that when users click it. its  opens (\10.10.0.1\k\Shared\HR) in windows explorer and not in the browser which it does now.

```
<li data-tags="Logo Design"><a href="\\10.10.0.1\k\"><img src="images/portfolio/thumbs/image(5).jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a>
```

this is the line i use.

i have read this links but they dont look to ans my ques, or i dont just understand what to do,

[Opening windows explorer via link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388641/opening-windows-explorer-via-link)

[Open ClickOnce application deployed in shared folder by a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568304/open-click-once-application-deployed-in-shared-folder-by-web-browser)

[Access a shared folder from a machine not in the domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736491/access-a-shared-folder-from-a-machine-not-in-the-domain)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249017/open-file-w-test-in-explorer-exe-not-in-chrome-or-internet-explorer-any        (this looks like what i need but i don't know where to fit in the code there)

[How to launch an EXE from Web page (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net)

am doing this on my system but will transfer it to the server, and will place a shortcut to my index file on users desktop.

Thanks for you help, I hope I have provide all the info needed to help me with this.

we all use chrome cause of google drive

Answer (score 0):

This will not be accomplished by any default browser configuration that I am aware of, as using `file://` references would typically cause the browser to try to launch the file. Maybe search though Chrome plug-ins to see if something is available there to override default browser behavior.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks, if i find a work around on the browser,  this will mean going round each user system to fix the, am trying to read about webdav and if it can be used.